# Flutter identify Widget built by loop or listview.builder

Tags: flutter, dart

I can't get around this issue, how do I select Widget built by for loop or a ListView.builder?
In code I will post, I have buttons built by for loop,
I want to change button's background color on click.

I'm using Provider in my project so this function is implemented with Provider.
In my Provider class I made a boolean and a function to switch that boolean, and then I assigned it to buttons, and set it's color to value of that boolean with ternary operator.

While this somewhat works, the problem is... All of the buttons built by the for loop are affected,
meaning. I press one button, all of them change color.
How do I fix this?

My widget which includes mentioned buttons:

```
ListView(
     children: [
      for(int i = 0; i < recipeIngredients.length; i++)
       IngredientsTab(
          ingredientText: recipeIngredients[i],
          textColor: categoryAndSeeAllColor,
          width: width,
          **buttonColor: provider.isButtonPressed ? accentColor : Colors.grey[100],**
          buttonIcon: Icons.add,
          buttonText: 'Add to cart',
          buttonTextColor: accentColor,
          **buttonAction: provider.changeBackground,**
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
```

In my Provider class:

```
bool isButtonPressed = false;

  void changeBackground() {
    isButtonPressed = isButtonPressed ? false : true;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

While I understand this happens for obvious reason, I'm assigning this `isButtonPressed` to all buttons so when its true they all change... So that makes sense, I just don't know how to solve it, I'm also having similar issue in another project where items are built with ListView.builder...

So if someone would help me with this would mean a lot to me :)

Comment: Make sure that, your widget can listen the changes that you made.. Can your widget listen your actions?

Comment: You can create a List<bool> isButtonPressed storing the value for each button. Then in your ListView builder instead of checking for a generic isButtonPressed, check for isButtonPressed[index]

Comment: @CarlosSR, good idea, but how would I define this List<bool>'s size? I don't know how many buttons will I get

Comment: @proversion it can ? Like I said it changes color..

Answer (score 1):

Usually you have in the Provider a List of Ingredients.
Each Ingredient have an ID and a bool selected variable.
The buttonAction calls the method with the ID:

```
void changeBackground(int ingredientID) {
    ListOfIngredients.singleWhere((elem)=>elem.ID==ingredientID)).isButtonPressed = !isButtonPressed;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Then you build the ListView using the List of Ingredients and for each Ingredient you check the isButtonPressed value.

Comment: How can I have ingredient and an ID in A LIST ?? .. Maybe youre thinking map? like "ingredient" : "id" but I dont have it like that... I have it as list of strings.. So this solution cant work.

Comment: @FlutterGuy A List of Maps [{"name": "cheese", "id": 1},{"name": "orange", "id":2}] or better a List of Objects: class Ingredient { final String name; final int id; Ingredient(name,id); }